# Querying a DataTable filtering for first char in field

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq & I can't figure out this query.

I have a dataTable with has a field "RecordType"
I want to get certain row fields filtered using the first letter of RecordType
the filter is a string "A,B" supposed to get only records with RecordType starts with A or B

my query is:

```
string filter = "A,B";
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
                .Where (row => filter.Contains(row.Field<string>("RecordType").Trim().ToUpper().First()))
                .Select(s => s["FieldA"])
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
```

I am getting "System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field(...) returned null."

What am I doing wrong?

And how to select multiple fields in the Select ?

Comment: Use substring method : row.Field<string>("RecordType").Trim().ToUpper().Substring(0,1)

Comment: It says what's wrong in the error. `System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field(...) returned null`. I've never personally worked with DataTables in C# but this usually indicates that it doesn't exist. As for selecting multiple items from the `Select` statement, you can return them as an array, create a new object with the fields you want and create a new instance of said object in the `Select` statement, or return an [Anonymous Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types). It all depends on the use case of course.

Comment: @jdweng,   still getting:    System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>(...) returned null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the error that you received, we need to explicitly tell the field call that the return type could be null (aka: `string?`).  Then, we need to check for a null value after the field call before trying to manipulate the string.

```
string filter = "A,B";
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where (row => filter.Contains(
        // get a nullable string from Field() and then use the "" value if it is null
        (row.Field<string?>("RecordType") ?? "")
            // pad the string to ensure there is at least one character to get in the substring call
            .PadRight(1)
            // get the first character of the string and upper-case it
            .Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()))
            .Select(s => s["FieldA"])
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I got the error:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Arg_ParamName_Name'

removing the null check

I got the usual error:
System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>(...) returned null

Comment: Ah - I've adjusted the code above to handle the empty string condition by padding the string to ensure there is at least one character.  This will ensure that the substring call doesn't cause an out of range exception.

Comment: - This also worked fine:
`.Where(row => docTypeFilter.Contains(
                   // get a nullable string from Field() and then use the "" value if it is null
                   (row.Field<string>("DocumentType") ?? " ")
                   // get the first character of the string and upper-case it
                   .ToUpper().First<char>()))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter using `StartsWith()`

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
       .Where (row => row.Field<string>("RecordType").StartsWith("A", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || row.Field<string>("RecordType").StartsWith("B", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
       .Select(s => s["FieldA"])
       .Distinct()
       .ToList();
```

---

If you want to consider a filter variable, then you can combine above query with `Any()`.

As your `filter` variable is separated by `,`, I used `.Split(',')` to convert string to string array.

```
string filter = "A,B";
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
       .Where (row => filter.Split(',')
       .Any(x => row.Field<string>("RecordType").StartsWith(x, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
       .Select(s => s["FieldA"])
       .Distinct()
       .ToList();
```

Comment: The filter is a variable - maybe "AQGN" to get fields starting with any of the letters contained in the filter string

Comment: @waleedhasan, please check my latest solution

Comment: still getting:  System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>(...) returned null.

Answer (score 0):

`.First()` will return the first row, not the first letter.

Try `s.Substring(0, 1) == 'A'` to check if the first character in the string is A

Comment: `StartsWith` is a better option than `Substring` in this case. Also in your answer it is unclear what `s` is and will probably confuse readers.